# My second button thing has a problem with return. if you can help please do, this is AppleScript editor

Tags: macos, applescript

```
display dialog "Error, Could not open chosen application. Try again in a few moments" buttons {"Report", "Ignore"} with icon 0
set the choice to the button returned of the result
if the choice is "Report" then
    display dialog "Reporting to apple" with icon 0
end if

set the choice to the button returned of the result
if the choice is "Ignore" then
    display dialog "ERROR ERROR. Computer Breached by Harmful Entity" with icon 0
end if
```

Comment: The `result` property contains the resulting value (if any) of the last statement executed.  Hint - the `if` statement is changing it.

Answer (score 0):

These minor adjustments to your code should accomplish what you're looking to achieve.

Inserting the `activate` command before any `display dialog` or `display alert` command will ensure that the dialog or alert windows dont get lost behind any other windows you may have open. It should bring them to the front

```
activate
set theChoice to button returned of ¬
    (display dialog "Error, Could not open chosen application. Try again in a few moments" buttons ¬
        {"Report", "Ignore"} with icon 0)
if theChoice is "Report" then
    activate
    display dialog "Reporting to apple" with icon 0
else
    activate
    display dialog "ERROR ERROR. Computer Breached by Harmful Entity" with icon 0
end if
```